# How to force set same page as homepage and blogpage in static page settings

Tags: database, dashboard, homepage, blog-page

I am trying to set the same page as my blog page as well as my static homepage. You might ask why i wanna do that, basically in the preview it shows me result that i am after, but i am not able to publish it as homepage and blogpage can't be same.

So, is there any way to either remove the validation so that i could publish the changes?
Or
To set the same page as home and blog page via db/php?

Comment: It doesn’t make any sense to want to do this. It suggests you’ve done something wrong somewhere. If you want your latest posts on the homepage, then you should select that option, and not have a static home page. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: The theme that i am using allows me to display all the pages as section of my homepage (like a onepage website) sorted in the page order if i set my blog page and my home page as the same page. At least the preview shows it that way. But it doesn't let me save it.

Comment: It sounds like something else is wrong. It doesn’t make sense that you’d need to do this to get your homepage to display a certain way. You should contact the theme author for help solving this properly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems validation was there only if I tried doing it via Appearance > Customize > Homepage settings.

However, it wasn't a hard violation if you set in via Settings > Reading.